# Trigger unhover / mouseout / blur on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mouseevent

On Javascript, ipad will threat hover as one click, and next click will be the real click event fired.

can we trigger unhover or mouseout or blur after first click on ipad, so next click after first click still will be hover event?

Answer (score 1):

To catch stuff on ipad you can look for these events
touchstart, touchend, touchmove.

To trigger something you can just do
$(element).trigger('event_name');

```
$('testElement').on('touchend', function () {
      $(this).trigger('mouseout');
});
```

Comment: your code don't revert to hover state. i already try mouseout, blur, but no one clear state of element. it still have hovered state. and next click will be real clicked event fired.

Comment: my code is only meant to show example of how to catch events on ipads, not meant to catch everything
If you want hover and trigger event on ipads then just set a flag to detect if the user touched or not. For example, add a class on touch, so you can check for that class every time the user touches, if the class is there then trigger event if not then trigger hover and add class. Make sure you remove class at some point so it resets